# How to filter/search for emails with a custom header field using Python imaplib?

Tags: python, imaplib, header-fields

I want to **filter emails** for the presence of a **specific custom header** field, e.g. `"X-my-header-field: my-header-value"`.
I am using **Python's imaplib**. I unsuccessfully tried the **search method**: `rv, data = mailbox.search(None, "X-my-header-field", 'my-header-value')`.

Does anybody have an idea or hint how to accomplish this? The idea is to filter the emails before downloading it from the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
mail.list()
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
result, data = mail.search(None, '(FROM "anjali sinha" SUBJECT "test")' )
ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
```

Comment: Thank you Vikas for your reply. I tried it your way: mail.search(None, 'X-my-header-field "my-header-value")') but I still get a runtime error:  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/imaplib.py", line 1055, in _command_complete
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command'] Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer with the hint of Vikas reply and reading [RFC 9051](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9051.html#name-search-command):

```
M.search(None, '(HEADER "X-my-header-field" "my-header-value")')
```